# Max type number for Ngx bootstrap date picker?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, twitter-bootstrap, ngx-bootstrap

How to limit date picker type for ngx bootstrap
Example if I type 04/25/199332132132 it is valid....
I want to limit if you type 05/25/1993 it is all limit for year is 4 number...

```
        <input type="text" placeholder="04/25/1993" class="d-inline input-item form-control font-weight-bold text-center datepicker-input mrg "
          autocomplete="off" formControlName="date" aria-label="date" name="date"
          bsDatepicker [bsConfig]="{ isAnimated: true }"/>
```

Comment: I would guess that the documentation for the calendar will tell you how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

as a way add `readonly` to input element so it can be only selectable from date picker.

```
 <input type="text" placeholder="04/25/1993" class="d-inline input-item form-control font-weight-bold text-center datepicker-input mrg " readonly
          autocomplete="off" formControlName="date" aria-label="date" name="date"
          bsDatepicker [bsConfig]="{ isAnimated: true }"/>
```

or add   `onkeydown="this.value = (this.value.length > 9) ? this.value.slice(0, 9) : this.value;"` to disable more than 10 chars

Comment: frriend .... i want ony to limit year on on four number and date for two... example you can only write 05/25/1993 and it is limit you can write 05/25/1999995 example...

Comment: Yes but how can you handle characters? User can also write alphabetic chars too. I edited answer with limit 10 chars.

Comment: what is this.value ?

Comment: Value of input element

Answer (score 1):

You should use the minDate and maxDate properties for this component as is in the documentation:

HTML

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 form-group">
    <input class="form-control"
           placeholder="Datepicker"
           ngModel
           bsDatepicker
           [minDate]="minDate"
           [maxDate]="maxDate">
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 form-group">
    <input class="form-control"
           placeholder="Daterangepicker"
           ngModel
           bsDaterangepicker
           [minDate]="minDate"
           [maxDate]="maxDate">
  </div>
</div>
```

TS

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
 
@Component({
  selector: 'demo-datepicker-min-max',
  templateUrl: './min-max.component.html'
})
export class DemoDatepickerMinMaxComponent {
  minDate: Date;
  maxDate: Date;
 
  constructor() {
    this.minDate = new Date();
    this.maxDate = new Date();
    this.minDate.setDate(this.minDate.getDate() - 1);
    this.maxDate.setDate(this.maxDate.getDate() + 7);
  }
}
```

Source: https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/datepicker#min-max